# Will the below XTAL Layout causes radiated emission from board

Tags: pcb, emc, crystal

I am debugging  a 6 layer board for RE issue and the stackup is (S G G P+G G S).This is a 6 layer board.

The microcontroller used is FS32K148UJT0VLQT and the XTAL circuit diagram is given below.

[image]

The layout is given below.Here the uC is placed in the Top layer and the XTAL is placed in
bottom layer(6th layer).

The layout is given below.

[image]

The uC is shown in red color XTAL is encircled in blue.This is a 32Mhz XTAL

The enhanced view of XTAL connection to uC is given below.

[image]

The trace shown in blue color is PTB6_XTAL and trace shown is red is PTB7_XTAL.

you can see that the traces are going from bottom to top and their length are also not same.

When I check the RE test result ,I can see some harmonics of 32Mhz.

May I know is this layout is causing that.

How can I improve the layout.

Comment: Just to be sure, there are ground planes under the crystal and under the MCU, and the crystal traces just basically go directly from MCU pins through vias to crystal?

Comment: Is there any layout guidance available from the MCU manufacturer? Some parts are pickier than others.

Comment: If the MCU is also running at 32MHz (or some multiple thereof) then it's impossible to say if the RE is from the xtal circuit or just the MCU.     An AUX_GND via placed really near the red and blue vias that carry the XTAL signals from L6 to L1 will help reduce the coupling of the xtal signal to other nearby signals _but_ I see that there are AUX_GND vias not so far away, so this isn't that likely, other than it will add to the GND noise seen by the MCU pins connected to those GND vias and this in turn might reappear on the IOs.

Comment: More likely than the via issue is that all of your decoupling caps seem to be on L6 with the MCU on L1.  If you are handy with the soldering iron I would try to add 0402 100nF caps across the actual pins of the MCU or soldered to the vias on L1.  If you can get all the VDD... pins that feed IOs this way it might help a lot.  When you decouple through vias, you are always going to get the IO switching signals producing voltages across the impedance of the vias and this noise is then on the whole plane.

Comment: Any MCU output pins feeding longish tracks that are toggling are likely to generate more RE than the crystal circuit. They will be locked to a sub multiple of the clock frequency but, because the edges are "fast" they will generate harmonics that make you think it's coming from the crystal circuit. It's the length of the IO tracks that are always going to be of more concern than the crystal interface circuit.

Comment: @RobinIddon,You are correct all decoupling capacitors are on L6.One doubt not related to this board. On BGA's the decoupling cap will be generally placed on bottom layer

Comment: @RobinIddon,May I know how decoupling CAP placed in L6 making RE issues

Comment: BGAs have on package caps to mitigate this.   Also the placement of those is much less inductive than your layout, typically.     You have RE issues.  I think it's more likely switching IOs than your crystal.  That leaves decoupling of VDDIO and the actual routing of any IO traces as the source of RE.  You could disable all IO switching in software and remeasure.  Then divide and conquer by selectively reenabling

Comment: But that is the consuming and expensive if you are renting RE lab.  So if it were me, I would add the VDDIO caps on L1 first and then do the IO  trace elimination second.   But it's your money 

Comment: @RobinIddon,We have a spectrum analyzer in the lab .I will try to do an initial check with that to see the peaks

Comment: If you can see the RE signal with no modifications then you can obviously compare the impact of various changes.  I haven't had much luck getting good correlation between RE chamber and those E/H field probes but you may have more success than me 